# tensorflow save shared variable inside library

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I formed a small LSTM unit with several hidden states. From the Tensorflow howtos I was able to save and restore state of the variables that are declared with tf.Variable. However, when I investigated the rnn_cell.py, I saw that there exists a function:

```
def linear(args, output_size, bias, bias_start=0.0, scope=None):
```

and inside there is a shared variable access

`matrix = vs.get_variable("Matrix", [total_arg_size, output_size])`

as far as I understand this matrix store the weights W_i, W_o, W_f and W_o, because after linear function, comes:

```
new_c = c * sigmoid(f + self._forget_bias) + sigmoid(i) * tanh(j)
new_h = tanh(new_c) * sigmoid(o)
```

So, I am willing to save and restore this variable as well. My question is where this is possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do? Current save/restore does not work for you?

Comment: 1 - What I read from another post is that save and restore doesn't save those variables (only saves the variables that you have defined in your own code, maybe it was wrong i didnt double check). 2- for speed: I have hundreds of training data files and when I train over these files, I restore and save state in the beginning and end of the file. Thus,  during processing of a single file in batches I need the values of Matrix at every batch (every 256 elements lets say) for some custom computation. Saving and restoring at every 256 elements I think can be costly (read/write io).

Answer (score 0):

For the records, it was possible to obtain the matrix via going deeper into the variable scope. `get_variable` requires dim info as well: `[2 * hidden_size, 4 * hidden_size]`

```
        with tf.variable_scope("RNN", reuse=True):
          with tf.variable_scope("BasicLSTMCell", reuse=True):
            with tf.variable_scope("Linear", reuse=True):
                v1 = tf.get_variable("Matrix", [2 * hidden_size, 4 * hidden_size])
                print(v1.eval())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access your tensor by evaluating it. for example to get the values of `matrix` you should evaluate and  it by ruuning as below: 
`ar = sess.run(matrix)
for row in ar:
  for col in row:
    # your method to save your data`

and you can build a class where your variables here are using as placeholder and you just feed them with loaded model that you have saved before!

Comment: true, I accessed them inside a session